# Inject third-party class without parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have created this class:

```
public class DbSchemaProvider : IDbSchemaProvider
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringFactory _connectionStringFactory;
    private readonly ISqlProviderNameProvider _sqlProviderNameProvider;

    public DbSchemaProvider(IConnectionStringFactory connectionStringFactory, ISqlProviderNameProvider sqlProviderNameProvider)
    {
        _connectionStringFactory = connectionStringFactory;
        _sqlProviderNameProvider = sqlProviderNameProvider;
    }

    public DatabaseSchema GetDbSchema(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        var connectionString = _connectionStringFactory.Create(sqlConnection.SqlConnectionType).Build(sqlConnection);
        var sqlProvider = _sqlProviderNameProvider.GetProviderName(sqlConnection.SqlConnectionType);
        var dbReader = new DatabaseReader(connectionString, sqlProvider, sqlConnection.Owner);

        return dbReader.ReadAll();
    }
}
```

Here I am using third-party class DatabaseReader which implements IDatabaseReader interface. I want to use it similarly to IConnectionStringFactory and ISqlProviderNameProvider - by injecting it into my class. However, I can't do it because IDatabaseReader can only accept required parameters (connectionString, sqlProvider, sqlConnection.Owner) through constructor. If I could use it with dependency injection, I would be able to unit test my class with IDatabaseReader mock. But now I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could wrap the `DatabaseReader` itself in an `interface`
Something like the following:

```
public interface IDatabaseReaderProvider{
    DatabaseReader Get(string connectionString, string sqlProviderName,  SqlConnection sqlConnection);
}
```

Then, you could inject `IDatabaseReaderProvider` to your `DbSchemaProvider` implentation and initialize the DatabaseReader in the 'Get' method

Comment: This creates dependency on a specific strongly typed instance (Tightly coupled) with Interface and beats the purpose of Interface. It may introduce complexity If user needs to change the implementation to  some different reader (SqlDatabaseReader)

Comment: And in the IDatabaseReaderProvider implementation, i just need to return `new DatabaseReader(connectionString, sqlProviderName, sqlConnectionOwner)` ?

Comment: @YanIvanEvdokimov yes, exactly

Comment: @VenkateshMuniyandi as I understood, you will only need to create a new implementation of `IDatabaseReaderProvider` if you want a different reader, so there are no tightly coupled classes.

Comment: @VenkateshMuniyandi the tight coupling is already there (DatabaseReader). The only way to remove this is by introducing and implementing a facade interface which might be a lot of work

Comment: @DanielS what if I make this interface generic, so it will return generic type instead of DatabaseReader? Will it be tight coupled anyway?

Comment: Got it :-) In Interface the return type should be marked as IDatabaseReader.  So that In implementation you can return any DatabaseReader that implements IDatabaseReader

public interface IDatabaseReaderProvider{
    IDatabaseReader Get(string connectionString, string sqlProviderName,  SqlConnection sqlConnection);
}

Comment: @YanIvanEvdokimov what if I make this interface generic, so it will return generic type instead of DatabaseReader? 
that sounds like a premature optimization. Unless, you anticipate changing  readers often or in the near future

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating DatabaseReader instance outside of DbSchemaProvider class. You can create instance of DatabaseReader in the class/method that creates instance of DbSchemaProvider and inject the IDatabaseReader into the constructor as you did for ISqlProviderNameProvider